# Invoke Method for Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to use Invoke Method for closing a form in Microsoft visual c++.

I want to know to create a delegate method for predefine closing method for Form which is close().

Kindly also tell me the way I can use Invoke method.

Comment: `private delegate void CloseForm();`
then I declare a method
 `public: void ClosingForm()
   {
    this->Close();
   }`
`CloseForm^ cc = gcnew CloseForm(this,);
cc->Invoke();`

but its not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a link to learn delegates use in C++.
And Its working right now..

http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/topics/delevents.htm